# Arduino Attiny85: analogWrite resolution

Tags: c, arduino, led, arduino-ide, attiny

This question is a follow-up of this hardware question:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266536/digital-optical-volume-control-with-led-and-photoresistor-light-to-seperate-cir
but this time it is about software, `analogWrite`.

I use an Attiny85 to control a self-made vactrol (A vactrol is a LED surrounded by Light Dependent Resistor in short LDR) to control analog audio volume. When the LED is at full brightness, the volume is at maximum level and when it is off it is at minimum level. To control the brightness of the LED, I use `analogWrite( PB1, 0..255 );`.

This is working pretty well, however, the difference between ON and OFF is a bit harsh. So when you do `analogWrite( PB1, 1 );`, the LED starts to glow at a certain level you didn't expect because it is only 1/255 of the total possible setting.

Is there a way to change the resolution, the sense of the `analogWrite` function?

Comment: analogWrite only works on pins with PWM enabled. Are you using the right pin to drive this?

Comment: @GandhiGandhi, that's not the question, did you read my question? To answer your question. Yes, I do.

Comment: Just checking. I saw you said the LED was brighter than expected; wrong pin was a possible cause.

Comment: I think you'll need a DAC to get the results you want instead of `analogWrite()`. It depends how the LDRs respond to the pulsed LED.

Comment: In fact it is working ok, only from zero to 1 is a little harsh. I also use code to set maximum PWM (32Khz instead of what it was) so the LDR's doesn't pick up any flickering and doesn't go down or up on PWM frequency. I cannot use a resistor because the overall performance of the led will decrease. I have also studied the arduino code of attiny but doesn't give any info how to change it. What do you suggest me to use?

Comment: I was thinking about using a hardware DAC as an alternate to `analogWrite`. Maybe something like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/935/1528-1010-ND/4990759?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla4990759&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1&gclid=CjwKEAiA2abEBRCdx7PqqunM1CYSJABf3qva7yimeDXIpKR15WC4UhpLJtgvHKJ6xx9AKZqznHlsEhoCh_jw_wcB)